# How to forbid overwrite in c++

Tags: c++

```
struct base {
    void foo() {}
};

struct derived : public base {
    void foo() {}
};
```

for example, I want above code has error or warning because they have same foo function in base and derived. Is there any compiler option or code analyzer can do that?

**You can not use "final", is overwrite, not override. It's not a virtual function.**

Comment: @Asesh You can not use "final", is overwrite, not override. It's not a virtual function.

Comment: If that's the case then it's not going to throw any error

Comment: so I want some compiler option or code analyzer like SonarCude can tell me that happened. @Asesh

Comment: This is not overwriting, this is called _name hiding_.